# ASP textboxes do not exist in context of Codebehind file

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I’m trying to write a basic ASP.NET form (using Visual Studio 2010) to submit numbers to a database.  Because this is a very early attempt for me to use ASP.NET, I wrote it very simply at first and now I am trying to add the remaining features.  Originally, everything was all inline code.  Now I am trying to switch it to use a codebehind page, but I cannot get it to resolve the names of my textboxes from within my codebehind file.  I built these pages while following some tutorials, and have looked at several other sources to try to fix this, but everything I’ve seen so far seems to indicate that I have it all set for a codebehind, yet it doesn’t work.  VS gives errors during compile, stating the textbox names do not exist in the current context.   When I remove all references to the textboxes, the page works and my button event fires.  For grins I added references to the textboxes in the codebehind, like so `protected TextBox XcoordTextbox;` (like I believe you would in ASP.NET 1.0) but then I get a runtime error `CS0102: The type 'ManualEntry.default_aspx' already contains a definition for 'XcoordTextbox'`
Below are the significant portions of my code.  Can you help explain why this doesn’t work?

**ASPX file**

```
<%@ Page    Language="C#" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="ManualEntry.default_aspx" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"></head>
<body>
    <form id="HtmlForm" runat="server">
        <div>
            X Coord&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="XcoordTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            Y Coord&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="YcoordTextbox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" onclick="SubmitButton_Click" Text="Submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind file**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace ManualEntry
{
    public partial class default_aspx : Page
    {
        protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Xcoord = XcoordTextbox.Text;
            var Ycoord = YcoordTextbox.Text;
            //More Code Here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Worst case, you should be able to do `this.FindControl("XcoordTextbox") as TextBox` to find your controls.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project? (Right click on the project in Solution Explorer and choose Clean)

Comment: @Mark - I have tried Cleaning it, but it doesn't seem to affect anything.

Comment: what is the cs file name of default_aspx class? is it default.aspx.cs?

Comment: @UnhandledException Yes.  The file names are default.aspx for the page and default.aspx.cs for the codebehind.  The class name should be irrelevant as long as it matches the `Inherits` property on the ASPX page, right?

Comment: @Tejs - So that did work.  I guess, as you say, I have my "worst case" option and can proceed if necessary.  Still, I would like to know what the heck is wrong since everything I've read so far says my original way should be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to `Microsfot.NET[.NET version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files.` and delete temparary files for your web site.

e.g for .net 4.0

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

if you use CodeFile directive then compiled files goes to Temporary ASP.NET Files

And also delete bin and object folders from your solution and rebuild the web application.

## EDIT

your default.aspx.designer.cs should look like below, don't add controls to this page manually.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ManualEntry {


    public partial class default_aspx {

        /// <summary>
        /// Head1 control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead Head1;

        /// <summary>
        /// HtmlForm control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm HtmlForm;

        /// <summary>
        /// XcoordTextbox control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox XcoordTextbox;

        /// <summary>
        /// YcoordTextbox control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox YcoordTextbox;

        /// <summary>
        /// SubmitButton control.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Auto-generated field.
        /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button SubmitButton;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a manual way to do the "Clean Solution" already mentioned.  I tried it anyway, but no change.

Comment: Regarding your edit... I don't seem to have a `default.aspx.designer.cs` page.  That sounds like something that could be causing behavior like this, but I don't know how they are added to a project or why I don't have one.
EDIT: I found this link [aspx.designer.cs how does it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284710/aspx-designer-cs-how-does-it-work) which includes information about regenerating the designer.cs file.  It appears to be working now.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem from time to time.
I usually do the followwing:

1. Go to default.aspx.designer.cs.
2. Make sure the namespace and class name are correct.
3. remove everything inside the `default_aspx` class.
4. Save and close default.aspx.designer.cs.
5. Make a change (add a space or something) to default.aspx.
6. Recompile the project.

It could also be your naming convention, try changing `default_aspx` to `default_aspx1`.  I have seen `default_aspx` used by .NET.
Also, in my .NET 4.0 the default is to use `CodeBehind` instead of `CodeFile`.  This seems to be the intended use case for all but [.NET 1.1](http://www.ashchuan.com/blog/2011/03/31/codefile-and-codebehind-in-net-what-the-heck-is-the-difference/).  See also [CodeFile vs CodeBehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73022/codefile-vs-codebehind)

If all else fails, try creating the page again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

your `CodeFile="default.aspx.cs"` statement is wrong

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
CodeFile="default_aspx.aspx.cs" Inherits="default_aspx"
```

Comment: If you notice my first block of code, I do have both of these, with the exception that my `Inherits` property includes the namespace qualifier.

Comment: NO, in your aspx you mention `CodeFile="default.aspx.cs"` and in cs `public partial class default_aspx`. They should be same and not different. Also, `Inherits` namespace not needed.

Comment: The `CodeFile` entry specifies the **file name** while the `public partial class` is the **class name**.  They are not the same.  I previously had different names before and it didn't work.  Just in case it was the names, I got these specific names from one of the tutorials I watched and it seemed to work OK for them.  Also, the `Inherits` property does require the namespace declaration because VS identifies it as an error if you don't include it ("cannot resolve symbol").

Answer (score 0):

use

```
CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs"
```

Comment: I already had the page listed as `CodeFile=` and it wasn't working.  Tried this one but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Your codefile tag in your asp must be the same of the class name. Try something like real class names. `HelloWord.aspx` or something.

Comment: As I mentioned in another comment, codefile and class names are separate.  From what I have seen it is only convention that says they should be the same.  Still I tried it.  Currently my Page is **MyPage.aspx**, codebehind is **MyPage.aspx.cs**, class is `public partial class MyPage : Page` and the page includes `Inherits="ManualEntry.MyPage` and `CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs"`.  It still gives the exact same errors.

Answer (score 0):

try changing your inherits to be `Inherits="ManualEntry.default"` instead of `Inherits="ManualEntry.default_aspx"`

Answer (score 0):

Go To your .aspx file and Re-check your Header like <%@............%>
there should be a link to your code behind file name which is .cs file like......

Checkout this 1....:)

```
{<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" **CodeBehind="Home.aspx.cs"** Inherits="MyCompany.Home" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master"%>}
```