# Hosting a webform page inside a web api. CS0103 control does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I need to add an ASP.NET web form pages to my ASP.NET API project. This is a legacy app that I don't have time to port over to the API & Angular just yet. The legacy page contains several controls including text boxes, drop down lists and a GridView control. All the code logic for the web form is contained in the code-behind page.

The problem I am running into is that when I try and rebuild the project the controls in the legacy web form are not recognized. I get the following error

`Error  CS0103  The name '<name of web control>' does not exist in the current context  MyWebApp C:\source_code\MyWebApp\api\services\LegacyWebForm.aspx.cs`

I get one of these errors for all the server side controls on the ASPX page.

I was pretty sure I could run this legacy web form inside of the API application and all I needed to do was add ...

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

My code behind file `LegacyWebForm.aspx.cs` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` and the ASPX page inherits the page class

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LegacyWebForm.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebApp.api.services.LegacyWebForm" %>
```

code-behind class name

```
namespace MyWebApp.api.services
{
    public partial class LegacyWebForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
...
```

Comment: Should be valid, you're not missing runats?

Comment: I do have `runat="server"` on the containing `<form>` element and all the controls

Comment: Is it registered in your `.aspx.designer.cs`?  (`protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox someTextBox;`, and does that file have the correct namespace?

Comment: That I am not sure off. I did not use the designer when I created it. Do you know where this file is located? The only files I moved over where the ASPX file and it's code-behind

Comment: [Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284710/aspx-designer-cs-how-does-it-work) It will be adjacent in the file hierarchy with the `.aspx.cs` code behind file [regenerating the designer](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328053551/http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/)

Comment: @UK_Dev - That did it! The link you provided to [Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284710/aspx-designer-cs-how-does-it-work) had all the instructions to regenerate the .aspx.designer.cs file. After that It compiled and ran. Thanks soo much! FYI - The answer from `David-Dietrich` contained the steps I followed.

Comment: Unfortunately it's something that you only discover after scratching your head for a while - glad to have helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a `designer` file.

`.aspx.designer.cs`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3284710/aspx-designer-cs-how-does-it-work) highlights the usage of a designer.

You can [regenerate](https://web.archive.org/web/20100328053551/http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/tip-regenerate-aspx-designer-cs-files-when-corrupted/) a designer file.

You may need to clean the project and rebuild it if the desiger file is still throwing missing references when you try to compile it.